# How to load the .bson collection for mongo in docker-compose

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

The following code for Docker and docker-compose.yml does not work properly, it fails to load sample_collection.bson into docker

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /salary_data_ggregation

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  bot:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongoimport:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo_import
    volumes:
      - ./bot/database/static_collection/sample_collection.bson:/data/sample_collection.bson
    command: mongoimport --host mongodb --db aggregation --collection sample_collection --file /data/sample_collection.bson

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo_db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    depends_on:
      - mongoimport
```

I expected to see an aggregation database and a sample_collection when I enter MongoDB Compass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the `depends_on` should be the other way around - the `mongoimport` service should wait for mongo to start before trying to import. Moreover, the host should be `--host mongo` instead of `mongodb`.

I would also recommend having a look in the recommended docker way of prepopulating data in mongo, by mounting a JS script under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, which mongo will execute. See the [Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)
 in docker hub.